# Smack - get entry starts with specific letter

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm using Smack to build simple XMPP android client, I need to retrieve users only starts with letter "a" I've tried to use roster and UserSearchManager both need specific user id I couldn't use wild card for e.g.

```
UserSearch userSearch = new UserSearch();
answerForm.setAnswer("user", "a*");
```

or

```
RosterEntry entry = roster.getEntry("a*");
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working snippet:

```
    public static List<Row> searchOnServerForUsers(String searchString, XmppManager xmppManager) throws Exception
        {
            UserSearchManager usersearchManager = new UserSearchManager(abstractXMPPConnection.getConnection());

            String searchServiceName = XmppConstants.USER_SERVICE_NAME_PREFIX + abstractXMPPConnection.getConnection().getServiceName();


            Form form = usersearchManager.getSearchForm( searchServiceName );

            Form answers = form.createAnswerForm();
            answers.setAnswer("Name", false);
            answers.setAnswer("Email", false);
            answers.setAnswer("Username", true);
  //        answers.setAnswer("search", "*");  //search for all registered users
answers.setAnswer("search", "a*");  //your search string

            ReportedData data = usersearchManager.getSearchResults(answers, searchServiceName);

            List<Row> rows = data.getRows();

            return rows;
    }
```

So you have to use `UserSearch`,

on each column (like `Username`, pay attention to case!)

you have to set if search (`true`) or to not search (`false`)

your `search` string (in your usecase: "`a*`")

Comment: I guess this goes with Openfire, I'm using ejabberd

Comment: It's openfire, but specs are the same. Check in debug what are the form key, 99% you'll find equivalent of 'search' key

Answer (score 0):

Don't use smack version 4.4.0 alpha1 it has some bugs. After reverting it to 4.1.1 . I got all the users. from UserSearchManager